# Voice chat between Node.js and browser (audio streams, VoIP)

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, browser, voip

I have done voice chatting between two node.js servers before (see: [tvoip](https://github.com/T-vK/tvoip)), which works quite well, but now I would like to do it between a node.js server and a browser. How could this be done?
From node.js to node.js I simply used raw PCM streams over a TCP connection.
For the browser this is probably not going to be that easy, right? I mean the browser doesn't really offer a TCP API. It does offer a WebSocket API, but does it handle streams? Would I have to convert the streams and if so into what format and how? What protocol should I use? Are there any helpful libraries to accomplish this already? Is [socket.io-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream) a viable library to send these kinds of streams?

From what I understand the audio streams are in the PCM format on the browser. So it should be compatble with the streams I got in Node.js. Is that assumption correct?

I have managed to pipe the browser mic input to the browser speaker output like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- alternative method that also works
<audio></audio>
<script>
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(function(stream) {
    const audio = document.querySelector('audio')
    audio.srcObject = stream
    audio.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        audio.play()
    }
}).catch(console.error)
</script>
-->
<script>
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(stream => {
        const aCtx = new AudioContext()
        const analyser = aCtx.createAnalyser()
        const microphone = aCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
        microphone.connect(analyser)
        analyser.connect(aCtx.destination)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error("Error getting audio stream from getUserMedia")
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I found two solutions. I will try to base the node<->browser voice chat on the second one.

For Node.js I came up with this code to pipe a node.js mic input to a node.js speaker output:

```
const mic = require('mic')
const Speaker = require('speaker')

const micInstance = mic({ // arecord -D hw:0,0 -f S16_LE -r 44100 -c 2
    device: 'hw:2,0',           //   -D hw:0,0
    encoding: 'signed-integer', //             -f S
    bitwidth: '16',             //                 16
    endian: 'little',           //                   _LE
    rate: '44100',              //                       -r 44100
    channels: '1',              //                                -c 2
    debug: true
})
const micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream()

const speakerInstance = new Speaker({ // | aplay -D plughw:CARD=0,DEV=0
    channels: 1,
    bitDepth: 16,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    signed: true,
    device: 'plughw:2,0' //'plughw:NVidia,7'
})
speakerInstance.on('open', ()=>{
    console.log("Speaker received stuff")
})

// Pipe the readable microphone stream to the writable speaker stream:
micInputStream.pipe(speakerInstance)

micInputStream.on('data', data => {
    //console.log("Recieved Input Stream: " + data.length)
})
micInputStream.on('error', err => {
    cosole.log("Error in Input Stream: " + err)
})
micInstance.start()

console.log('Started')
```

Finding the right `device` for mic and speaker can be a bit tricky if you are not familiar with ALSA under Linux. [It is explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/53957/what-do-alsa-devices-like-hw0-0-mean-how-do-i-figure-out-which-to-use) in case you are unsure. I am not certain how it works on Windows and Mac OS with SoX.

I then came up with a small test application to connect the two ideas using socket.io-stream (a socket.io library that allows sending streams over a socket). And obviously, this is where I'm stuck at.

Basically, I try this on the node.js side:

```
const mic = require('mic')
const Speaker = require('speaker')
const SocketIO = require('socket.io')
const ss = require('socket.io-stream')

...

io.on('connection', socket => {
    let micInstance = mic(micConfig)
    let micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream()
    let speakerInstance = new Speaker(speakerConfig)

    ...

    ss(socket).on('client-connect', (stream, data) => { // stream: duplex stream
        stream.pipe(speakerInstance) //speakerInstance: writable stream
        micInputStream.pipe(stream) //micInputStream: readable stream
        micInstance.start()
    })
})
```

and this on the browser side:

```
const socket = io()
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(clientMicStream => { // Get microphone input
    // Create a duplex stream using the socket.io-stream library's ss.createStream() method and emit it it to the server
    const stream = ss.createStream() //stream: duplex stream
    ss(socket).emit('client-connect', stream)

    // Send microphone input to the server by piping it into the stream
    clientMicStream.pipe(stream) //clientMicStream: readable stream
    // Play audio received from the server through the stream
    const aCtx = new AudioContext()
    const analyser = aCtx.createAnalyser()
    const microphone = aCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
    microphone.connect(analyser)
    analyser.connect(aCtx.destination)
}).catch(e => {
    console.error('Error capturing audio.')
    alert('Error capturing audio.')
})
```

The whole code can be viewed at: https://github.com/T-vK/node-browser-audio-stream-test
(The [README.md](https://github.com/T-vK/node-browser-audio-stream-test/blob/master/README.md) contains instructions on how to set it up, if you want to test it.) The relevant code is in [server.js](https://github.com/T-vK/node-browser-audio-stream-test/blob/master/server.js) (The setupStream() function contains the interesting code.) and [client.html](https://github.com/T-vK/node-browser-audio-stream-test/blob/master/client.html).

As you can see I'm trying to send the duplex stream over the connection and pipe the microphone inputs into the duplex stream and pipe the duplex stream to the speaker on each end (like I did it in [tvoip](https://github.com/T-vK/tvoip)). It does not work atm, though.

Edit:

I'm not sure if I get this right, but the "stream" that I get from [getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) is a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) and this media stream can have [MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack)s (audio, video or both). I'm my case it would obviously just be one track (audio). But a `MediaStreamTrack` doesn't seem to be a [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) as I know it from Node.js, meaning that it can't just be piped. So maybe it would have to be converted into one. I found this interesting library called [microphone-stream](https://github.com/saebekassebil/microphone-stream) which claims to be able to do it. But it doesn't seem to be available as a simple browser library. It seems to require wrapping your whole project with browserify. Which seems very overkill. I'd like to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

There exists a standard for doing VoIP with browsers that is supported by all mayor browsers: [WebRTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC). Although being a dreadful beast of complexity, it is supported out of the box by all mayor browsers which hide its complexity. I am no javascript developer, but I highly assume that there exists gold support for it in the JS world, look at e.g. [this blogpost](https://bloggeek.me/nodejs-webrtc/).

If you do not want the full-featured overkill solution, I would draw back to RTP as a streaming protocol , which is kind of standard in VoIP and Opus for encoding. 
Both are well-established technologies and form kind of the default pair of VoIP streaming, RTP is leightweight, and Opus efficient in compressing while rtaining high audio quality. They ought to be well-supported in either the Browser and node.js environments.

Beware: If you decide to send plain PCM, precisely define all the parameters - frame length (8, 16, 32 bit), a
signed/unsigned, integer/float and expecially *endianness* !

Answer (score 2):

You should not use raw PCM streams directly to connect browser and nodejs app together. It can become pretty wasteful in no time.

on the other hand, what works in node, may or may not work in browser (going to check your repo to see what you are trying to do and check if i can check something there)"

Another solution, would be to use a server - like icecast -, which will make all the backend/data nitty gritty stuff.

Then you interact via web browser just with an html tag.

Check this -> ()
I had a link to a related thread in stack overflow, but i lost IT Lol()

Hpe you find this useful,
Regards.

Comment: I'm not looking for an effiient solution yet. I need to get it to work at all first. And since PCM is the default/native format, I'd like to stick to that for now. Compressing/encoding and decompressing/decoding the stream is a problem for another time and out of scope for this question. Setting up third party software like icecast isn't really an option. I want to do it with Node.js and of course it has to work in both directions, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

[SFMediaStream](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/SFMediaStream) can help you stream microphone audio data from the browser, and you can broadcast it with `socket.io`. The audio data is encoded in `opus` depending on the browser.

It also has feature to give audio filter/effect for the streamer, and you can also use the library for build a video/audio player.

Maybe you will interested after check this [basic example](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/SFMediaStream/tree/master/example/StreamingTest)

Answer (score 0):

One of the Library that you must work its [socket.io](https://socket.io) and one of the best tutorial its [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQjiN8Qgs3c&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i4V-_ZVwLmOusj8YAUhj_9). you can learn it and after you made chat app in node.js then start voice chat app

Comment: I already know how to use it, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to send PCM streams over it.